# How to automate working with Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to detect memory leaks in my web app. I have a simple procedure:

Refresh, start recording, collect garbage, click a button, click another button, collect garbage, click a button, click another button, collect garbage, stop recording.

Is there a way to automate this process so I wouldn't have to click manually every time I change sth in the source code an I need to reevaluate the timeline?

(I'm on Mac OS)

Comment: Paul's automated-chrome-profiling is probably the closest to what you are looking for. It requires a node instance and running chrome with an open debugging port: https://github.com/paulirish/automated-chrome-profiling#readme